# rails 3.0.10 conditions in select()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, conditional-statements

i have this select

```
<%= select("post", "field",@variable.all.collect) {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, :include_blank =>'blank')%>
```

to generate a dropdown of 4 registers

and i did

```
{|p| [ p.name, p.id ] if helper_method(p.id) }
```

expecting this output:

```
blank
reg4
```

instead i got this output:

```
blank



reg4
```

and i can't figure out how to get the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@variable.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] if helper_method(p.id) }` will return something like `[["blank", 1],nil,nil,nil,["reg4", 2]]`, because every time the `helper_method(p.id)` condition is not met it returns nil to the collect. This is giving you your blank options for the nil values, so a simple solution would to be remove the nils by using `.compact`

```
@variable.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] if helper_method(p.id) }.compact
```

There are other ways, you could avoid returning nil in the first place and just remove the options in another passing like so:

```
@variable.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }.reject{|p| !helper_method(p1)}
```